# Using a between Date in SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, between

Im using vb.net code with Sql Server 2008 R2.
I'm trying to get result by using a SQL query to get all rows that have a value between 2 dates:
Here is my the `where` clause of my statement:

```
Where (CONVERT(varchar(10), visit_nextVisitDate, 103) between '02/04/2017' AND  '15/05/2017')"
```

but I always get all rows for the same month (month 4).
I tried this:

`WHERE (CAST(dbo.Visits.visit_date AS date) BETWEEN '24/04/2017' AND '02/05/2017')`

but I got an error cause my date fields are saved in format `yyyy/mm/dd`

How can I change the SQL date format to `dd/mm/yyyy`?

Answer (score 6):

Why would you do date comparisons using strings?  That is just wrong, wrong, wrong.  (If you do it, use ANSI standard formats, YYYY-MM-DD so the comparisons are correct.)

Just do this using dates:

```
Where visit_nextVisitDate between '2017-04-02' AND '2017-05-02'
```

Actually, it is a bad idea to use `between` with dates.  Aaron Bertrand has a very good [blog](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) on this subject.

I recommend:

```
Where visit_nextVisitDate >= '2017-04-02' AND 
      visit_nextVisitDate < '2017-05-03'
```

Comment: but how if i want use the following format dd/mm/yyyy in my sql??

Comment: @EyadShahroury . . . I strongly recommend that you use the ISO standard date formats.  If you really insist on other date formats, I would suggest that you explicitly convert the *constant* values to dates using `convert()`.

Comment: OK , I will :) , THANKS