# Trying to get dates between 2 dates in PHP using SQL

Tags: php, sql, date

I am using this query to get all the dates between 2 dates:

```
$getDates="SELECT daily_rate_date FROM daily_rates  WHERE daily_rate_date BETWEEN '".$checkOut."' AND '".$departureDate."' AND daily_rate_reservation=$reservationId;";
```

The thing is that if for example `$checkOut = 03-03-2021` and `$departureDate = 07-03-2021`, I get the dates:

```
04-03-2021
05-03-2021
06-03-2021
```

but i also need the $checkOut date too to be included (but not the $departureDate) :

```
03-03-2021 
04-03-2021
05-03-2021
06-03-2021
```

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: `WHERE daily_rate_date >= '".$checkOut."' AND daily_rate_date < '".$departureDate."'` ? See also how to [Use prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/9193372)

Comment: Almost duplicate (different language but basically the same), but I believe that this is the answer that you want. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43633362/498699

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then change your query to:

```
$getDates="SELECT daily_rate_date FROM daily_rates  
           WHERE daily_rate_date >= '".$checkOut."' 
           AND   daily_rate_date < '".$departureDate."' 
           AND   daily_rate_reservation=$reservationId;";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `>=` and `<` operators instead of `between` for you use case.

```sql
$getDates="SELECT daily_rate_date FROM daily_rates  WHERE daily_rate_date >= '".$checkOut."' AND < '".$departureDate."' AND daily_rate_reservation=$reservationId;";
```